# Remove text which are surrounded by box in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I wanted to remove the text that is surrounded by the box. How can I do this? I'm working on this image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/edinB.png]

Below is the code which I use for making boxes

```py
#  Finding Outlines and Screening Text Areas
region = []
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i in range(len(contours)):
    cnt = contours[i]
  
    # Calculate contour area and screen out small areas
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if (area < 80):
      continue
  
    # Find the smallest rectangle
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    print ("rect is: ")
    print (rect)
  
    # box is the coordinate of four points
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
  
    # Computing height and width
    height = abs(box[0][1] - box[2][1])
    width = abs(box[0][0] - box[2][0])
  
    # According to the characteristics of the text, select those too thin rectangles, leaving flat ones.
    if (height > width * 3):
      continue
  
    region.append(box)
  
    # Draw outline
    for box in region:
      cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0), 1)
  
      cv2.imshow('img', img)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "remove text"?  Do you want the boxes to be empty or do you want to determine what the text reads in each box?

Comment: I just wanted where ever boxes are created just remove the text inside the box